# Unable to mount datastore on second ESX 5.5 host

Tags: vmware-esx, shared-storage

I have configured 2 ESX 5.5 hosts on my new Dell VRTX. I setup the virtual storage, assigned full access to both hosts, and was able to format and attach it to ESX1 without an issue. Unfortunately I haven't been able to present the datastore on ESX2.

ESX2 sees the hba, and I can attach the storage device to the host, but I can't get the datastore to mount. I can detach and reattach the device, and all the LUN info shows up under device details. Rescan, refresh, still no datastore.

I must be overlooking something simple because I've never had this problem before... maybe it's the VRTX?  Any suggestions will be much appreciated, and hopefully before I do any more damage from banging my head on the desk for the past 24 hours.

Thanks

Comment: You really ought to contact support for some input if you purchased ProSupport with the system, there could be a pretty easy answer for this.